# Array - how to replace record with newly added

Tags: php, arrays

I got the array below and I would like to keep recent added record which is [2] and delete others

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [is_sub] => 0 [product] => New [quantity] => 1 [price] => [total_item_price] => 0 [comments] => ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [is_sub] => 0 [product] => Old [quantity] => 1 [price] => [total_item_price] => 0 [comments] => ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 4 [is_sub] => 0 [product] => Mix [quantity] => 1 [price] => [total_item_price] => 0 [comments] => ) )
```

Comment: try http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php

Comment: this is replace the data... but i want to remove [0] and [1], and keep the 3rd record or most recent record [3]/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got an answer thanks for helping.

```
$last = array_slice($orders, -1, 1, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

```
$last = array_pop($orders);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$last_data = array_pop($data);
print_r($last_data);
```